# How can I play a sound when script execution is ready?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, audio

I am executing every now and then some python scripts which take quite long to execute.

I execute them like this:
`$ time python MyScript.py`

How can I play a sound as soon as the execution of the script is done?

I use Ubuntu 10.10 (Gnome desktop).

Comment: Are you using `bash` or `zsh`?  There are actually some ways of making this happen automatically, but they're quite involved and depend on which shell you are using.

Comment: $ echo $SHELL returns "/bin/bash"

Comment: Same question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/277215/how-to-make-a-sound-once-a-process-is-complete

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Append any command that plays a sound; this could be as simple as

```
$ time mycommand; printf '\7'
```

or as complex as

```
$ time mycommand && paplay itworked.ogg || paplay bombed.ogg
```

(Commands assume pulseaudio is installed; substitute your sound player, which will depend on your desktop environment.)

Comment: +1 `paplay` is probably the best command to use to play a sound on a "modern" Linux system.

Comment: printf '\7' doesn't work for me, but this command worked as I wanted it `time python MyScript.py -n 40 && paplay /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/desktop-login.ogg || paplay /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/phone-outgoing-busy.ogg`

Comment: `printf '\7'` works for me (paplay doesn't; (git shell)) but it's just a very small *bip*. Are there more codes that make other sounds? I tried `\6`, `\8` but they are some characters.

Comment: @laggingreflex No, `\7` (BEL) is usually the only character that possibly triggers a sound (see the Wikipedia article [Control character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character)); note that it may not always make a sound, either.

Comment: `paplay` works well for me. You find a nice free notification sound from CyanogenMod, https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/tree/cm-12.0/data/sounds/notifications. I'm using `ogg/Adara.ogg` which has a light percussive sound.

Comment: @laggingreflex You probably don't need this any more but just for laughs ;) `for i in {1..30}; do for j in {1..3}; do printf '\7'; sleep 0.12; done; sleep 0.4; done`

Answer (score 34):

**`spd-say`**

```
sleep 2; spd-say 'get back to work'
```

Infinite loop with `-w` if you need extra motivation:

```
sleep 2; while true; do spd-say -w 'get back to work'; done
```

or if you prefer the carrot:

```
sleep 2; while true; do spd-say -t female1 -w "I'm done, come back to me, darling"; done
```

Pre-installed on 14.04 via package `speech-dispatcher`: http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64.manifest for blind people I suppose?

**Also add a popup**

This combo is a life saver (`b` stands for `beep`):

```
b() ( spd-say 'done'; zenity --info --text "$(date);$(pwd)" & )
```

and then:

```
super-slow-command;b
```

If I'm somewhere in the room, I'll hear it and know that the long job is done.

Otherwise, I'll see the popup when I get back to my computer.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035/how-to-show-a-gui-message-box-from-a-bash-script-in-linux

Comment: To get the `spd-say` tool associated with `speech-dispatcher`, you may need to install a subpackage like `speech-dispatcher-utils` (Fedora 24).

Comment: Brilliant! I used to use `beep` but it became so complicated to configure, `spd-say` it's a super cool readily available alternative!

Answer (score 9):

Just pick a sound on your hard drive, and put a command to play it right after the command you're waiting on; they'll happen sequentially:

```
$ time python MyScript.py; mplayer ~/ScriptDone.wav
```

(You can use any player, naturally). I have a script called `alertdone` that plays a tone and shows an libnotify alert when run; I use it for exactly this occasion:

```
$ time python MyScript.py; alertdone "Done timing"
```

It's really simple, so if you want to make your own you can base it on this (mine requires `notify-more`, `mplayer`, and `~/tones/alert_1.wav` though):

```
#!/bin/bash
message=${1:-"Finished working"}
notify-more -t 10000 -i /usr/share/icons/gnome/32x32/actions/insert-object.png "Process Finished" "$message"
mplayer ~/tones/alert_1.wav
```

Comment: `notify-more` or `notify-send` could indeed be useful alternatives to playing a sound.

Comment: @Mikel I'm completely addicted to libnotify; everything on my system pops up notifications

Comment: Arch Linux has a list of “any player”: [Multimedia#Audio players](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/List_of_applications/Multimedia#Audio_players). My favorite is [mpv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpv_(media_player)).

Answer (score 8):

```
time python MyScript.py; play /path/so/sound.ogg
```

`play` is a very basic (no UI) sound player from the [sox](http://packages.ubuntu.com/sox) [Install sox http://bit.ly/software-small](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/sox) package. You can replace it by any other command-line-driven sound player.

Comment: Yep, `play`, `aplay`, or `paplay`.  (My Ubuntu system has `aplay` and `paplay` by default.)

Comment: `time python MyScript.py -n 40; paplay /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/desktop-login.ogg` worked, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I use `my-script && notify-send "done"`. This sends a desktop notification, which on Linux Mint(Cinnamon) looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can also make this happen automatically.

I will show you how in `zsh`, then add info about `bash`.

The essence looks like this:

```
preexec()
{
    starttime=$SECONDS
}

precmd()
{
    if ((SECONDS - starttime >= 5)); then
        aplay "sound.wav"
        # or printf "\b", or notify-send, or whatever
    fi
}
```

You can also make it only do it if the program was Python, e.g.

```
preexec()
{
    starttime=$SECONDS
    case $3 in python*)
        command_is_python=true;;
    *)
        command_is_python=false;;
    esac
}

precmd()
{
    if $command_is_python && ((SECONDS - starttime >= 5)); then
        aplay "sound.wav"
        # or printf "\b", or notify-send, or whatever
    fi
}
```

In `bash`, the best way is to download [preexec.bash.txt](http://www.twistedmatrix.com/users/glyph/preexec.bash.txt) and source it (e.g. `. ~/preexec.bash.txt` at the top of your `~/.bashrc`, then the above (or something close to it) should work.  (Not sure about the `$3` bit to check if the command is Python.)

If you're using GNOME Terminal, I would also point you to [Flashing GNOME Terminal](http://mikelward.com/software/gnome/flashing-terminal).  It's a patch I wrote that makes the terminal blink when a command is done, so you can Alt-Tab to something else, then it lets you know when it's done.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add a command to everything, you can actually use a script, that does this automatically for you. It is called [undistract-me](https://github.com/jml/undistract-me) and it is available on Github.

example

```
sudo apt install undistract-me    #installs the script (on Debian)
echo 'source /etc/profile.d/undistract-me.sh' >> ~/.bashrc #adds auto-enable to your console
echo 'export LONG_RUNNING_COMMAND_TIMEOUT=XXX' >> ~/.bashrc #where XXX is number of seconds when the command is long enough to alert you
echo 'export UDM_PLAY_SOUND=1' >> ~/.bashrc #to enable sound alert
```

now start new bash and you are set. Sound and alert can be changed by modifying the script.