# Can I change default return action on an empty terminal prompt?

Tags: shell, prompt

Basically, I'd love to be able to be able to configure my terminal to run a `ls` command when I ***don't*** put anything on a terminal prompt and I press enter.

If return is pressed in the shell on an empty prompt, it does nothing (as expected) and returns an empty prompt (as expected).

Tried to look into config files and settings with several terminals / shells with no avail. I mainly use fish if that helps.

I'm sure that someone already had this idea but I'm struggling to find the right keywords for this kind of request and I couldn't find any info.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: For *bash*, you could probably adapt this: [tell if last command was empty in PROMPT_COMMAND](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226909/tell-if-last-command-was-empty-in-prompt-command)... for fish, perhaps this will help [fish equivalent to precmd/PROMPT_COMMAND](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2942)